# Use xUnit runner result as playlist for VisualStudio Test Explorer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, automated-tests, xunit.net

Is it possible to somehow use the result of the xUnit runner (running automatically every night) to somehow create a playlist of failed tests or other type of file that can be run by the Test Explorer in Visual Studio?

The use case here is that we got a nightly run that has a variable amount of failures and we would like to quickly check which of those work when run from VS so we can work on those that are actually failing because something is wrong. Since these range from 1-100 and it's different tests each time it'd be great to not have to look up all of the tests each time by hand.